# Switching base language in Qt desktop application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, internationalization

**What is the recommended way to scan Qt Desktop GUI source files for tr() translation strings and replace them in-place in the source code, with strings from another language?**

Is this simply a job for a regex or is there something in Qt C++ source (for example, lupdate.exe) that could reasonably be used for modifying the source files? Or is there a more standard / idiomatic Qt way to do this?

*Background:*

Our source code has UI strings in Finnish. I would like them to be in English  and then use qt translation to get Finnish.

Also I will then generate a new .ts file for the Finnish strings (that are currently in the C++ source files), but dealing with XML is easy in Qt anyway.

We've been building a desktop application with Qt for about 8 years. Along the way, it turned out that we should have used English as the source language (duh), and not Finnish. But we never had the time to do the switch, and now there are way too many strings to switch manually.

Comment: Consider starting the opposite way .. by _generate a new .ts file for the Finnish strings (that are currently in the C++ source files)_,  This is a good [reading](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq03-swedish-chef.html) to start with

Comment: "put on hold as too broad by eyllanesc, Jesper Juhl, WebDevBooster, aghilpro, Reaz Murshed 2 days ago"

I would really like to understand what is "too broad" about this question. Please provide assistance. To me, the goal is technically trivial and straightforward to define, so it should not be considered unreasonable to allow Qt professionals a chance to provide direction.

Comment: I didn't say it's _too broad_ in my comment? I just gave you a start point?

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I'm happy for your help. It's not you I'm questioning, it's the "on hold" status set for the entire question. 

Specific advice on what you suggest is welcomed too though - I am not sure I see how the document you linked to relates to what you suggest.

Comment: I put that link because it puts you in a start point.